# Getting 429 error only for mobile app traffic

Tags: php, mysql

We have a mobile app and a web app for the same application server. When users access the system through web app it works fine, but when try to accessing from the mobile app it gives 429 error code from the server.

I tried by reducing the traffic to server by allowing only one external IP from the firewall and that time both mobile and web app works fine. It seems no of concurrent connections doesn't affects to the web app but it affects to the mobile app. Mobile app calls to the server through server host name through an API.

Comment: 429 is usually from server or app configuration so we can't really know what's wrong without more info

Comment: thank you for your comment, what would be the "more info" which might help to solve the issue?

Comment: 429 is a response that usually only is returned when a server is configured with a rate limit. Some examples of more details would be the server configuration, any differences to how the mobile and web app users connect to your server (is it a different host?), those sort of things